# Dynamically change module register name and decorator parameters using configService in NestJS

Tags: redis, queue, nestjs

framework : NestJS

I am currently managing the queue by communicating with redis.

And I am using configService as cross-env.

Here is the code for AppModule, AudioModule and AudioService.

```
< AppModule.ts >

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      isGlobal: true,
      envFilePath: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
    }),
    BullModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: () => ({
        redis: {
          host: "localhost",
          port: 6379,
        },
      }),
    }),
    AudioModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}




< AudioModule.ts >

@Module({
  imports: [
    BullModule.registerQueueAsync({
      name: "audio",
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        name: configService.get<string>('QUEUE_NAME', 'audio-test')
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService]
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AudioController],
  providers: [AudioService],
})
export class AudioModule {}



< AudioService.ts >

@Injectable()
export class AudioService {
  constructor(@InjectQueue("audio") private audioQueue: Queue) {}

  async getJobById(jobId: JobId) {
    return await this.audioQueue.getJob(jobId);
  }
}
```

I want to dynamically change the queue name according to the dev, test, and prod environments using configService.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

injecting the ConfigService into the AudioModule and using it to get the value of the QUEUE_NAME environment variable.

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { BullModule } from '@nestjs/bull';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
    BullModule.registerQueueAsync({
      name: 'audio',
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => ({
        name: configService.get<string>('QUEUE_NAME', 'audio-test'),
      }),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AudioController],
  providers: [AudioService],
})
export class AudioModule {}
```

You can set the `QUEUE_NAME` environment variable in the `.env` files for each environment (dev, test, prod)

```
QUEUE_NAME=audio-dev
```